# Saving ignored / favourite tags won't apply sometimes

Tags: support, tags

I don't know whether it's my internet connection, the ajax script or just the stack-network. Sometime when I add mew tags to my favourites or ignored list, it won't apply immediately. I have to wait ~15 sec. Otherwise the tag will disappear from the list again. Could anyone tell my, why this happens?

Comment: Still nobody? This is getting more and more annyoing ...